# Copying Data from one table to another with updated date

Tags: mysql, sql, heidisql

I've two tables 2017_11_08_minute and **2017_11_09_minute**. My **2017_11_08_minute** table is empty. I need to copy all the data from **2017_11_09_minute** to **2017_11_08_minute**.

I've a DATETIME column in my 2017_11_09_minute which has data like 2017-11-09 00:00:20

I need to update this to 2017-11-08 00:00:20 while copying the rest of the data as it is!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reduce 1 day from the date column value then use **`DATE_SUB`** function.

**Query**

```
insert into `2017_11_08_minute`(`col_1`, `col_2`, `col_2`)
select `col_1`, `col_2`, date_sub(`date_col`, interval 1 day)
from `2017_11_09_minute`;
```

Or we can use even **`DATE_ADD`**

**Query**

```
insert into `2017_11_08_minute`(`col_1`, `col_2`, `col_2`)
select `col_1`, `col_2`, date_add(`date_col`, interval -1 day)
from `2017_11_09_minute`;
```

Comment: Okay. Works like a charm!  And just another thing. Similarly how do we add or subtract general data? Assuming I want to add or subtract a common value from a column.

Comment: @AthreyaSridhar : What do you mean by **`add or subtract general data`** ?? Please specify clearly with examples.

Comment: Sorry. Assume I have 10 rows of data in column named 'data'. I have to subtract or add a numeric value from or to all the ten rows.

Comment: If it is numeric values, simply use the arithmetic operations like `+`, `-`.